# How can I get the solarized color theme for MATE terminal?

Tags: themes, mate

I would like to have the [solarized theme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) in MATE 1.6 terminal. How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using this:
https://github.com/oz123/solarized-mate-terminal

Install *git* on your system.
Then in a terminal run

```
git clone https://github.com/oz123/solarized-mate-terminal.git
cd solarized-mate-terminal
./solarized-mate.sh dark
```

or

```
./solarized-mate.sh light
```

restart the terminal and enjoy.

Comment: I meant 'profile', sorry. Menu "Terminal" -> Change profile. Can you see the solarized profile there?

Comment: Never mind, it seems to work. I should have read the README...